# How to create a lock for a specific variable in main while using queues in threads

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, queue, locking

I am trying to figure out how in python one would declare a specific variable to be locked so that only one thread may access it at a time to avoid race conditions. If I have two threads constantly updating a variable via queues, but I am also updating the variable manually in main, what would be the right way to declare that variable a shared resource by all threads so that only one may access it at a time between the threads being run and main?

I wrote a little example code to show what I mean.

```
import time

from random import randint
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

# Add the amount by random number from 1 - 3 every second
def producer(queue, amount):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        amount[0] += randint(1, 3)
        queue.put(amount)

# Subtract the amount by random number from 1 - 3 every second
def consumer(queue, amount):
    while True:
        item = queue.get()
        amount[0] -= randint(1, 3)
        queue.task_done()

amount = [10]

queue = Queue()
t1 = Thread(target=producer, args=(queue, amount,))
t2 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(queue, amount,))

t1.start()
t2.start()

while True:
    n = input("Type a number or q: ")
    if n == 'q':
        break
    else:
        # Here is where I am confused about how to declare the amount a
        # shared resource and lock it in a way that the queues would also 
        # adhere to
        amount[0] += int(n)
        print("amount is now: {}".format(amount[0]))

t1.join()
t2.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to lock the variable when you are updating the value of it. so in your case indeed you require locking mechanism.

How to lock:

create a `threading.Lock` object which will help you lock and release the block of code.

- acquire : to lock the code block. only one thread can enter in this block. other thread will wait until it is released.
- release : to release the acquired lock.

In your case:

```
import time

from random import randint
from threading import Thread,Lock
from queue import Queue

# Add the amount by random number from 1 - 3 every second
def producer(queue, amount,lock):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        lock.acquire()
        amount[0] += randint(1, 3)
        queue.put(amount)
        lock.release()

# Subtract the amount by random number from 1 - 3 every second
def consumer(queue, amount,lock):
    while True:
        lock.acquire()
        item = queue.get()
        amount[0] -= randint(1, 3)
        queue.task_done()
        lock.release()

amount = [10]
lock = Lock()
queue = Queue()
t1 = Thread(target=producer, args=(queue, amount,lock))
t2 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(queue, amount,lock))

t1.start()
t2.start()
 ...
```

Comment: Why would I need to lock the queue put and get? I am not updating the value of amount there right? Only when I do the addition, subtraction to amount in the producer/consumer functions and in the while loop in main so I would then use the example you showed me but around the reassignment of amount right?

Comment: you are absolutely right, sorry i did not notice it before. but i guess you are clear with how to lock and release the block of code.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the clarity! I am new to concurrency in python and was just really curious how python handles it since coming from C to python can cause me to overthink alot. Your example on using locks was clear and concise! Thank you